# Vertically middle align text in a div

Tags: html, css, alignment

my demo is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hrhktkbzyy/6b6s03ts/1/

html:

```
<div class="container divinline">
    <div class="firstrow">
        <div class="col1 divinline">COLUME 1</div>
        <div class="col2 divinline">COLUME 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondrow">ROW TWO</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.divinline{
    display:inline-block;
}

.container{
    height:80px;
    background:#ffee12;
    width:50%;
    text-align:left;
    color:#FFF;

}

.firstrow{
    background:#450011;
    height:60%;
    font-size: 0;
}

.secondrow{
    background:#333333;
    font-size:12px;
    height:40%;
}

.col1{
    background:#ffff00;
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    font-size:12px;
}

.col2{
    background:#ff0000;
    height:100%;
    min-width:30%;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

What I want to do is to vertically align the text 'COLUME 1' and 'COLUME 2' to the middle(or to the bottom).

Anybody can help will be highly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `line-height`

```
.firstrow{
   ...
   line-height: 50px;
}
```

Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6b6s03ts/3/)** *(your jsfiddle)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` to do that. Works for all browsers from IE 8 upwards.

[JS Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6b6s03ts/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd reccomend the "line-height" approach as well. But in case you are not sure of your divs height for sure, you can always use simple jquery for this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $('.firstrow').height();
    $('.divinline').css('line-height', height + 'px'); 
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6b6s03ts/9/)